# Only space between location and date

Tags: biblatex

In my bibliography a book should be displayed as follows:

> Darwin, Charles. The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821-1836. Cambridge 1985.

The first part works fine. What can I add to the code so the title is followed by the address and the year (without a comma or a full stop inbetween)?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
    Author = {Charles Darwin},
    address= {Cambridge},
    Title = {The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821-1836},
    Year = {1985}}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla \autocite{darwin} \autocite{wade}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `biblatex-ext`'s drop-in replacement for `verbose` (`ext-verbose`), you can just redefine the macro `\locdatedelim`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
  author  = {Charles Darwin},
  address = {Cambridge},
  title   = {The Correspondence of {Charles} {Darwin}, 1821--1836},
  year    = {1985},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{darwin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Darwin, Charles. The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821–1836. Cambridge 1985.]

If you can't or don't want to use `biblatex-ext`, you can redefine the macros directly. Either

```
\newcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\newcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcolon\space}
\newcommand*{\publocdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}

\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}

\renewbibmacro*{location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

to get the same functionality as `biblatex-ext`, or something more specific like

```
\newbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}

\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}
```

which would suppress the `publisher` if given.