# Customize Incollection style

Tags: biblatex

The Incollection style looks like this:
[image]

However it should look like this:
Vader, Darth. "How to beat darth vader". In: *Star Wars*, hg. v. Skywalker, Luke und H. Solo. Naboo 2018, pp. 130-154.

So the following things need to be changed:

1. add hg. v. before publisher
2. replace semicolon with comma
3. the name of the publisher should be first the surname and then the 
   forename; the second publisher should be his initial and then the surname
4. After the publisher there should be a fullstop instead of a comma
5. The address should be displayed before the year

How can I change those things?

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @InCollection{vader,
        author    = {Darth Vader},
        title     = {How to beat darth vader},
        booktitle = {Star Wars},
        year      = {2018},
       %  address    = {Naboo}
        publisher = {Luke Skywalker; H. Solo},
        pages = {123-134},
    }
    \end{filecontents}



    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \renewbibmacro[article]{in:}{}



    \begin{document}
    Cite \footcite{vader}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Editors (*Herausgeber*) of a work are given in the `editor` field, the `publisher` contains the publishing company (*Verlag*). Name lists are always separated with `and` regardless of the desired output.

I'm using my `biblatex-ext` style as a basis, because it allows for a slightly quicker solution to some issues, cf. [Only space between location and date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464636/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman] {babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authortitle, articlein=false]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given/given-family}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  byeditor = {hg\adddotspace von},
}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{incollection:parent}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:innamebeforetitle}
    {\usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{innametitledelim}}\newblock}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{edition}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{barevolume+volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{vader,
  author    = {Darth Vader},
  title     = {How to beat darth vader},
  booktitle = {Star Wars},
  year      = {2018},
  address   = {Naboo},
  editor    = {Luke Skywalker and H. Solo},
  pages     = {123-134},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Cite \footcite{vader,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma und Ulf Ryde. „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Vader, Darth. „How to beat darth vader“. In: Star Wars, hg. von Skywalker, Luke und H. Solo. Naboo 2018, S. 123–134.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right the two names should be the editor not the publisher. You gave my quite some work. I've already spent three hours trying to get biblatex-ext running :). I hope I'll manage to get it running tomorrow and then test your code.

Comment: @derd You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466742/35864

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to differentiate the formatting of the publishers names, except directly in the .bib file. For the rest  here is a proposition, redefining the macro `publisher+location+date`:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{vader,
    author = {Darth Vader},
    title = {How to beat darth vader},
    booktitle = {Star Wars},
    year = {2018},
    location = {Naboo},
    publisher = {Skywalker Luke, H. Solo},
    pages = {123-134},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch} 

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{Hg. v.}\setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}%[article]

\begin{document}

Cite \footcite{vader}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure L. Skywalker & H. Solo are not `publisher`s in the `biblatex` sense, they are quite probably `editor`s. If one goes with `editor = {Luke Skywalker and H. Solo},` the output is already much closer to the desired result, there are only a few details that need to be tweaked (see my answer).

Comment: @moewe: I thought two publishers was strange, too. As I don't really speak German, I couldn't be sure, of course, so I did what I could..