# Unable to install biblatex-ext

Tags: biblatex

I tried to install the biblatex-ext package via tlmgr. I'm using TeX Live 2017 and Ubuntu 18.04.

```
tlmgr install: package biblatex-ext not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

I didn't find a similar question in the WWW. I hope that the question is in the right forum. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: the first version was released in march 2018, so probably it isn't in texlive 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first official release of `biblatex-ext` is dated 2018-03-18 and was announced on CTAN on [19th March 2018](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2491.1521492821.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org). TeX live 2017 was frozen around [2 March 2019](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-March/041108.html) (for more on these freezes see [Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864)), so `biblatex-ext` did not make it to TeX live 2017 and is only available in TeX live 2018 and above.

The recommended way to install `biblatex-ext` is via a TeX distribution that ships it, so in this case installing TeX live 2018 (probably the vanilla version from TUG if you are using Linux [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)) is the way to go. Then `biblatex-ext` is either installed already or can be installed with `tlmgr`.

---

If that is out of the question, you can install the package manually. This is *explicitly discouraged*, but possible.

The newest version available on CTAN was written for `biblatex` 3.12 and should not be used with older versions of `biblatex` that can be found in TeX live 2017 (a regular TeX live 2017 should have `biblatex` 3.10 at most).

Older releases of `biblatex-ext` can be found at https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/releases. Versions 0.1 up to 0.5a were all written for `biblatex` 3.11. They were not tested with older version of `biblatex` and they will issue a warning if used with an older version, but most things *should* work with `biblatex` 3.10.

For TeX live 2017 I would recommend to download v0.5a from https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/releases and follow *Method 3* in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864).